# How does Google know I am behind a SOCKS proxy?

Tags: proxy, privacy, socks-proxy, geolocation

Setup: Ubuntu Desktop, Firefox without Flash or Java, using Socks 5 proxy, wired connection, all history/cookies cleared.

All other websites, including IP and location detecting sites like simplesniff.com and whatismyipaddress.com see me as coming from the proxy IP. If I use a Canadian IP for my SOCKS 5 proxy, a lot of sites will offer me the .ca version. Somehow Google still knows where I am. When I go to news.google.com it shows me local news and local weather for my real location, not my proxy IP.

How could they be getting this information?

Comment: Is your proxy adding the [`X-Forwarded-For`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For) header?

Comment: Have you deleted Flash cookies, too? See http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/it-security/flash-cookies-whats-new-with-online-privacy/

Comment: Sorry if this is a dumb question, but are you signed into Google?

Comment: If you search for "what is my ip" on Google, the search engine itself should tell you what it thinks your IP is. If it's really your IP, then you've probably set up your proxy incorrectly, in which case you should post screenshots of what your network settings are.

Comment: Are your DNS lookups going through the proxy? Google serves different DNS results for different locations, and the DNS results are part of how they choose which country's version to show you.

Comment: Is HTTP**S** traffic going through your proxy? Some proxies only do non-secure traffic.